# warning received at objectsAtIndexes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am trying to fetch data from core data, it works fine. But when I try to fill a Table Cell then it gives me warning at the following line

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [fetchedObjects  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Warning : passing argument 1 of 'objectsAtIndexes:' makes pointer from integer without a cast.

fetchedObjects is an NSArray object declared in header file. Kindly guide me where I am doing wrong. I can provide whole method for more understanding.

Regards.

**EDIT**

Here is my complete method code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    


UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];

cell.textLabel.text = [fetchedObjects  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Hmm. I don't believe that is your code, as it couldn't possibly generate that error (unless you're playing some crazy macro games).

Comment: well this is mine :) and i figure out the original problem. It is because I have multiple columns in core data and i was assigning here only single index which is not sensible enough :) Well thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code says you're calling `objectAtIndex`, which does indeed take an integer parameter. However, your error says you're using `objectAtIndexes`, which takes a pointer to an `NSIndexSet`. As `indexPath.row` is not an `NSIndexSet` pointer, you're getting that warning (saying that you're trying to use a raw integer as a pointer).

Check your actual code. Almost certainly, you're using `objectAtIndexes` by mistake.

Comment: kindly see my edited part sir, I give the whole method of UITableView Cell insertion which obviously needs the ObjectAtIndex parameter.

Comment: My point is that you're not calling `objectAtIndex`. The error indicates you're using `objectAtIndexes` - a completely different method!

Comment: I think I have to recode this one. As far as I understand, its the problem of having multiple columns in 1 entity. Well I see it again then will get back to you. Thanks a ton!